# AngularJS: Intercept non xhr requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to intercept non xhr requests with Angular?
I have this problem where if a user types in the URL, say `/admin`, the server returns a 401 if the user isn't logged in. But because the request is not xhr, it is not intercepted, and thus the user isn't redirected to the log in page.

This works for my xhr requests like this:

```
$provide.factory('authorizationService', ['$q', '$injector', function ($q, $injector) {
    return {

        // Success: just return the response
        response: function (response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },

        // Error: check for the 401 error status
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401)
                $injector.get('$state').transitionTo('users.login');
                return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}]);
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authorizationService');
```

EDIT: I can redirect non authorized non xhr request on the server side, but I'd like to have it in one place.

Comment: Can you use HTML5's `pushState` with your client base?

Comment: @IshanChatterjee By clients base do you mean which browser they will use?

Comment: Yes, exactly. AngularJS supports routing through using `pushState` which moves from the `#/admin` type of URL to using `/admin` which is a "vanity" URL. If that was the case, then you can easily intercept with the same model that you have above.

Comment: @IshanChatterjee If the problem is the `#`, wouldn't it work if I used html 5 mode?

Comment: @kjelelokk: Could you ever solve this issue? I face the same...

Comment: @Dunken: Sort of, I think. Sorry 'bout the late reply. I don't think I was able to intercept a xhr request, but I basically fixed it on the server side. A non-xhr request was always the first request, so the server responded to that by returning my layout file (contining header, footer, etc). The Angular would ask for the content that actually needed authentication with an xhr request. So I had a middleware running auth on specific routes when the request was a xhr, and just calling next() on normal requests. Roughly. There is a little bir more, but I am running out of space for a comment.